# How elasticsearch updateByQuery syntax works

Tags: elasticsearch, nestjs, update-by-query, elasticsearch-client

I've been working with Elasticsearch for some days. As i'm creating a CRUD, I've come across the [updateByQuery method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update-by-query.html). I'm working with nestjs, and the way that I'm updating a field is:

```
await this.elasticSearch.updateByQuery(
            {
                index: 'my_index_user',
                body:{
                    query:{
                        match:{
                            name: 'user_name',
                        }
                    },
                    script: { 
                        inline : 'ctx._source.name = "new_user_name"'
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

My question is:
Why does elasticsearch need this syntax `'ctx._source.name = "new_user_name"'` to specifie what the new value of the field **name** should be? What is ctx._source is this context?

Comment: Hope my answer explains what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official doc of source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#source-filtering), using this you can fetch field value in the `_source` (Value which sent to Elasticsearch and this is stored as it is, and doesn't go through the analysis process).

Let's take an example of `text` field for which `standard` analyzer(Default) is applied, and you store the value of `foo bar` in this field, Elasticsearch
breaks the value of field as it goes through the analysis process and `foo` and `bar` two tokens are stored in the inverted index of Elasticsearch, but if you want to see the original value ie `foo bar`, you can check the `_source` and get it.

Hence, it's always better to have the original value(without analysis process) to be in the `_source`, hence using this API, you are updating the field value there.. **this also helps when you want to reindex later to new index or change the way its analyzed as you have the original value in _source**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And what about the `ctx` before ._source?

Comment: @PedroSG https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-ctx-to-access-source-field/115129 refer for more info